# java streams to sort a list sorted on an object property casted from string to int

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Given a list of objects that have a "key" property which is a string, is there any way I can use streams *.sorted()* method so that it treats the key as an int and uses the key to sort the objects?

Let's use this as an example

```
public class Book {
 public String key;
 public String title; 

 public Book(String key, String title) {
    this.key = key;
    this.title = title; 
 }

// Getters and Setters omitted from example but assume they exist
}

Book book1 = new Book("1", "A good book");
Book book2 = new Book("2", "A bad book"); 

List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
bookList.add(book2);
bookList.add(book1);
```

My goal in this case would be to sort the book list using streams and the key property so that book1 becomes the 1st element and book2 becomes the second element.

I have tried something like this but I still seem to get exceptions.

```
List<Book> sortedList = bookList.stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(b -> Integer.parseInt(b.getKey()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Does anyone notice anything immediately that would cause this to fail? Any clarification is much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear why you're trying to use an int comparator to compare Strings. Why wouldn't you use the natural ordering for strings?

Comment: By the way, this code works for me (assuming the syntax fix, adding the missing close-parenthesis at the end of the `sorted(...` line). Not sure why you feel the need to use a stream just for sorting, though.

Comment: @E-Riz Notice the OP passed String encapsulated integers to the constructor and then parsed them.  The natural order for Strings is lexical which means that 11 would come before 2.  But I agree it would be best if the key was as an integer from the start and forget about Stringed numbers unless it is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a `getKey()` getter to your class to return the `key`
- Add one more closing parenthesis `)` to `sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(b -> Integer.parseInt(b.getKey()))`

But you can also sort `bookList` in place as follows

```
bookList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(b -> Integer.parseInt(b.getKey())));
```

Note:  If you use a constructor of `Book(int key, String title)` and change the types of `key` and the `getter` to `int` you won't have to parse the String.  Then you could do:

```
bookList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getKey));
```